# Get 401(Unauthenticated) error after login on laravel sanctum with nuxtjs

Tags: php, laravel, nuxt.js, laravel-sanctum, nuxt-auth

I have installed:

- laravel `v 7.30.4`
- nuxtjs `v 2.15.7`

After i login in my laravel sanctum with nuxtjs auth module, when nuxt try to get user, laravel response 401 error(Unauthenticated message).

My network status:
[image]

My cookies status:
[image]

`api.php`:

```php
    Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:sanctum'], function (){
       Route::get('/user', function (Request $request){
          return $request->user();
       });
    });
```

`nuxt.config.js` :

```js
   auth:{
    strategies: {
      'laravelSanctum': {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000',
        endpoints:{
          login:{
            url:'/login'
          },
          logout:{
            url:'/api/logout'
          },
        },
        user:{
          property:false
        }
      },
    },
    redirect:{
      login: '/auth/login',
      logout:'/',
      home:'/'
    },
    cookie: {
      options: {
        sameSite: 'lax'
      },
    },
  },
```

`LoginController.php` :

```php
    public function login(Login $request)
    {
        $user=User::where('phone_number', $request->phone_number)->first();
        if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)){
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return response()->json(null, 201);
        }
        return $this->setStatusCode(422)->respondWithError('password','invalid pasword');
    }
```

`.env` :

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost

SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000
```

I don't know where is problem that i get 401 error!

Comment: Can you achieve to make this work via Postman?

Comment: Hey man, did yo get that to work? I am having exactly the same issue here.

Comment: Hi. I switched my authentication method and used JWT authentication. You can see my project in https://github.com/hotel-motel . Furthermore, you can config it like Sacntum in Nuxt.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, the solution was to add localhost:8000 (laravel domain) to SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:8000,localhost:3000
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to return your `api token` after logging in. and send it in every request that you use `middleware('auth:sanctum')` in laravel route.

more info about [issuing tokens in sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#issuing-api-tokens)

getting user requires `token` and if not provided it with throw **401** error.

Comment: it not api token auth, it spa auth : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authentication

Answer (score 1):

on your .env you can add this
`SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false`

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` to the `api` middleware groups within your application's app/Http/Kernel.php file?

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful;

protected $middlewareGroups = [
  ...
  'api' => [
      EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class, // Add & import this class
      'throttle:60,1',
      \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
  ],
];
```

This is necessary if you are using sanctum with an SPA app. This has been documented as part of the [Installation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#installation)

Also take a look at this section to see if the issue you are having is related to [CORS in Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#cors-and-cookies)

Comment: i did it first :) i see document and did it but iit did not work

Comment: Are you using the `nuxt/auth` package. If not, can you try using that instead and see if that fixes the issue? https://auth.nuxtjs.org/providers/laravel-sanctum/
Here is another blog post on its usage https://swapnil.dev/blog/authentication-in-nuxtjs-using-laravel-sanctum/

Comment: @OmidRezaHeidari, did you get anywhere close to solving the issue yet or are you still getting 401 error?

Comment: i get 401 response yet !

Comment: @OmidRezaHeidari did you manage to resolve this by any chance?